# Flutter Firebase google authentication error

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

In my Flutter application, I got a strange error suddenly. It was working well 1 week ago, but after a week, when I run the app, it didn't work and gave the following error.

```
W/song.vixen(19815): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getUnsafe()Lsun/misc/Unsafe; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/song.vixen(19815): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->objectFieldOffset(Ljava/lang/reflect/Field;)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/song.vixen(19815): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->compareAndSwapObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/song.vixen(19815): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/song.vixen(19815): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->compareAndSwapObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z (greylist, linking, allowed)
E/SpannableStringBuilder(19815): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(19815): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/flutter (19815): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(exception, BAD_REQUEST, null, null)
E/flutter (19815): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:597:7)
E/flutter (19815): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:158:18)
E/flutter (19815): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (19815): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:358:43)
E/flutter (19815): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (19815): #3      GoogleSignInAccount.authentication (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:90:9)
E/flutter (19815): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (19815): #4      _LoginPageState.signinWithGoogle (package:vixen/view/vixen_signin.dart:130:51)
E/flutter (19815): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (19815): #5      _LoginPageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:vixen/view/vixen_signin.dart:407:33)
E/flutter (19815): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (19815):
```

> Following is my authentication part in my app.

```
Future<void> signinWithGoogle() async{
    final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn(); 
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser!.authentication;  // ==> I got error here.
    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken, idToken: googleAuth.idToken);
    UserCredential authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
```

I added the ssh1, ssh256 key already to the Firebase account, and got the json file from Firebase.
But I am still getting this issue continuously.
How to solve this issue? I think this error doesn't related with my local env. After getting this error, I reinstalled Android Studio, and updated JDK, Flutter SDK also.

But still getting same error. What is the reason?